# Read Only error MySQL phpAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have been at this for hours now, and I cannot get it to change from Read Only to where I can INSERT rows. I am using phpMyAdmin and getting the following error.

A picture of the error
[image]
I have been through quite a few of the other question/answer topics on Stack and I cannot find an answer to my problems.

If anyone can assist me, that would be great!

Comment: you dont have access to write to table. It can be either your operating system user has no access to write on file or your mysql user has not granted to update this table. your db folder OS user and group should be mysql:mysql

Comment: I'm getting an error from pma_recent saying it is read only.

Comment: @Rodrane I have been using this database since I created the application on this computer. The problem only started yesterday when I tried to add more data to the database.